# Unreadable data in Mysql from a GeoDjango PointField

Tags: mysql, geodjango

I'm using GeoDjango with MySQL. I use a `models.PointField(srid=4326)` object, all works fine, the data is correctly saved and retrieved from the database, but when I do a `select * from table` from MySQL command line, data of `PointField` field shows unreadable characters, instead of a `POINT(x,y)` form, as I expected.

Is it a normal behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is normal.  The data is stored in a binary format.

Try `select AsText(geom) from table` where 'geom' is the name of your geometry column.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ST_AsText` for storing points

```
mysql> SELECT ST_Y(Point(56.7, 53.34));
+--------------------------+
| ST_Y(Point(56.7, 53.34)) |
+--------------------------+
|                    53.34 |
+--------------------------+
mysql> SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Y(Point(56.7, 53.34), 10.5));
+-------------------------------------------+
| ST_AsText(ST_Y(Point(56.7, 53.34), 10.5)) |
+-------------------------------------------+
| POINT(56.7 10.5)                          |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

you can refer to the link for more detail:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-point-property-functions.html